# Applescript iTunes Reveal

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

Is it correct that the reveal applescript command is broken with iTunes 9?

Works:

```
tell application "iTunes"
 play (track "Los")
end tell
```

Doesn't work:

```
tell application "iTunes"
 reveal (track "Los")
end tell
```

But the following does work:

```
tell application "iTunes"
 reveal (playlist "Music Videos")
end tell
```

Can anyone reproduce this behavior? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check ou this tut from [Doug's applescripts for itunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/itunes72info.php)

Answer (score 0):

The correct code segment should be ::

-- select a specific track

```
tell application "iTunes"
    reveal (track "Woo Hoo" of playlist "Music")
end tell
```

The `playlist "Music"` bit is necessary even when the song is in your main library (ie in the Music list). If it's in another playlist, you can specify that instead.

Example ::

-- select a specific track in another playlist

```
tell application "iTunes"
    reveal (track "Woo Hoo" of playlist "Sleepy Songs")
end tell
```